# Rotational group of a circle

Tags: group-theory

I have to show that the rotational group of the circle has elements of order n for each n and also elements of infinite order.

A circle has infinite lines of symmetry and so has rotational order of infinity. 
This is what I know with respect to the question. How should I go further?

Answer (score 1):

Rotation by $\frac{2\pi}n$ has order $n$ and rotation by any angle $\alpha$ that is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ has infinite order.

Comment: Where can I read more about this?

Comment: But isn't the definition of the order of an element the smallest positive integer such that $$a^n=e$$?

Comment: By convention, Math, if there is no such positive integer, then we say the order is infinite.

Comment: How would we prove that any $\alpha$ that is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ has infinite order. Wouldnt this rely on the fact that $\pi$ is irrational. Is there a more elementary proof of this statement?