# Proof that the group of rotations of the circle has elements of infinite order.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, irrational-numbers

Firstly, I am aware that this question has been asked twice before. [First Time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309016/rotational-group-of-a-circle) . [Second Time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518351/group-of-symmetries-of-circle-contains-elements-of-all-orders).

My question is really about the validitiy of these answers. Note that in the first answer the proof relies on the irrationality of $\pi$, while the second proof only relies on the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

It feels to me that there should be some flaw in this second proof, but I can't say exactly what it is.We see that if she/he were to replace "360" with "$2\pi$" the proof would not work. Any help towards a resolution would be awesome.

A followup question (assuming proof two is wrong): Is there any proof of this that does not rely on the irrationality of $\pi$?

Comment: True $\pi$ is transcendental, while $\sqrt 2$ is "merely" irrational.  Nonetheless, $n r \ne q$ for irrational $r$ and rational $n, q$

Comment: The first proof is not relying on the irrationality of $\pi$.  It is relying on the fact that there are irrational numbers.  Rotation by any irrational multiple of $\pi$ will work.  I think part of your confusion is due to the fact that the first proof is in radians and the second is in degrees.

Comment: You're right, the proof does not rely on the irrationality of $\pi$. I think this fixes the original misunderstanding but now I have a new one haha: If angle $\alpha$ not a rational multiple of $\pi$ why is it true that $k \alpha \neq 2m\pi$ for $m, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Contrapositive: if $k\alpha = 2m \pi$, then $\alpha = \frac{2m}{k} \pi$ where $\frac{2m}{k} \in \Bbb Q$ since $m, k \in \Bbb Z$. Thus $\alpha$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.